# button_to not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have a button_to helper method in a view table that I cannot get to work the way I need it.  I am using it to delete a record in a different model than is building the table and I do not have the :id for but I do have other parameters that can find the proper record.  Based on other questions here I think the following sytax should be the correct;

`<%= button_to 'Remove',mailing_list_edit_path(:arg1 => "value1", :arg2 => "value2"),:method => :delete,:confirm => "are you sure?" %>`

but I get this error when I click the button;

```
Routing Error
No route matches [DELETE] "/assets"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.
```

Here is the entry in my routes.rb

```
resources :mailing_list_edits, only: [:create, :destroy]
```

And the action in my controller

```
def destroy
MailingListEdit.where(:att1 => params[:arg1], :att2 => params[:arg2]).delete_all
respond_to do |format|
format.html { redirect_to controller1_index_path(session[:remember_token]) }
end
end
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What's the output of `rake routes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a workaround, in case it will help someone else, here it is.

The path helper would not work without an :id, so I included a dummy :id and now I am able to pass the two attributes I needed to find and destroy.  So my button_to now looks like this;

`<%= button_to 'Remove',mailing_list_edit_path(:id => "foobar", :arg1 => "value1", :arg2 => "value2"),:method => :delete,:confirm => "are you sure?" %>`

Kind of a hack, but it works!

Answer (score 3):

I think you don't give the object to destroy to you link. Indeed the destroy method built by the ressources is a member route: it needs the object to destroy.

For exemple: 
`<%= button_to 'Remove',mailing_list_edit_path(@object_to_destroy, :arg1 => "value1", :arg2 => "value2"),:method => :delete,:confirm => "are you sure?" %>`

Comment: What if I dont have the object but enough info to find it in the destroy action?

Comment: In this case, You need to create a route which is a collection (not a member) with a new method in your controller. However, if you can find your object in your controller to destroy it you can find it before in your view to use the destroy member route.

Comment: Cupra, Thank you, that was helpful but I found a work around that solved the problem for me.  See my answer.